# Short story where a Vietnam vet is hunted in his dreams by an undead native

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story probably around the beginning of the 1990s.  I believe it was in a compilation of the year's best short stories -  sci-fi, fantasy, and horror. It was a small paper back book.  The story that I remember in particular was pretty riveting and more horror than sci-fi or fantasy.

- It was about a Vietnam vet that was taking drugs to keep himself awake because he was having nightmares of stuff that occurred to him during the war.
- The vet recalled one particular night battle where this montagnard (mountain people in Vietnam) soldier's body was found.

  - The odd thing about the body they discovered was that it had pointy teeth.
- I think they put the body in a morgue like area that night and the next day discovered the other bodies in there had been torn open and feasted upon.
- In the vet's dreams, the montagnard soldier was slowly crawling towards him and getting closer every night.  It got to the point where he didn't want to sleep anymore and was taking drugs.

I don't remember much about the rest of the story. If anybody can help me figure out the name of the story, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[Graves](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41353)" (1992) by Joe Haldeman, first published in *Fantasy & Science Fiction*.  It was anthologized in several 1993 *Year's Best* collections, including Dozois' and Datlow's, but they were all trade paperbacks.  The only paperback reprinting appears to be in Haldeman's collection [*None So Blind*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24454).

The story itself is exactly as you describe it.

Comment: Thanks David!!!